# Read stored data with AS3

Tags: database, actionscript-3, air

I would like to create an AIR app that can read and search into a table (xml file ? xls file ? don't know the simpliest).

Example : 
I've got a table with 500 lines and 6 columns.

[image]

I would like to tell my AS3 code :

```
If ("date == 6 July" && City == "San Francisco"){
show the hours();
```

Do you know the simplisest way to do something like that ?

---

**EDIT**

Thank you Aaron for your answer. And so, with xml, can I do that in my AS3 code ? : 
I'm trying to search in my xml variables.

For example, I've got in my AS3

```
var currentDate=new Date();   
var month=currentDate.getMonth()+1;  
var day=currentDate.getDate();   
var months:Array = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];  
var my_date:Date = new Date();   
var today =(day+" "+ months[my_date.month])
```

I'm trying to do that :

```
var results:XMLList = myXML.row.(city == "San Francisco" && date == today);  
   if(results.length()){  
   for each(var row:XML in results){  
  trace(row.haute, row.basse, row.haute2, row.basse2);  
   }
```

But it's not working.

How can I tell in an other working way that I want the code to search date == today ?

Comment: Where is the table located?

Comment: in the same folder. At the moment it's an xls file.

Comment: @user3094896 Of course using XML file is more easy than XLS one. For searching, take a look on [my answer for your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31113054/2256820).

Comment: For your edit, you need to use `month` or `my_date.month + 1`. Other than that it looks right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML is the way to go. AS3 supports [E4X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript_for_XML) syntax which allows you to query an XML object easily.

For example, your XML could be structured like this:

```
<xml>
    <row>
        <date>1 July</date>
        <city>San Francisco</city>
        <hours1>6h50</hours1>
        <hours2>1h14</hours2>
        <hours3>20h01</hours3>
        <hours4>13h16</hours4>
    </row>
</xml>
```

Then you can query it like this:

```
var results:XMLList = myXML.row.(date == "1 July" && city == "San Francisco");
if(results.length()){
    for each(var row:XML in results){
        trace(row.hours1, row.hours2, row.hours3, row.hours4);
    }
}
```

Comment: Super ! It works. Just one question in my new edited post.. if you know the answer it will be awsome.

Comment: Sorry, bad written. Is it possible to do : date == today (I've edited my post).

Comment: Yep that's possible. The code you posted looks like the right idea. Just make sure the formatted date looks right and there are matching data.

Comment: Yes, you can use local variables in the e4x expression.