# select specific data in a xml file

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I've got this xml file

```
<data-set xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <record>
        <Date>1 July</Date>
        <Ville>New-York</Ville>
        <haute>6h50</haute>
        <basse>1h14</basse>
        <haute2>20h01</haute2>
        <basse2>13h16</basse2>
    </record>
    <record>
        <Date>2 July</Date>
        <Ville>New-York</Ville>
        <haute>7h36</haute>
        <basse>1h59</basse>
        <haute2>20h41</haute2>
        <basse2>13h56</basse2>
    </record>
    <record>
        <Date>3 July</Date>
        <Ville>Miami</Ville>
        <haute>8h21</haute>
        <basse>2h44</basse>
        <haute2>21h22</haute2>
        <basse2>14h37</basse2>
    </record>
</data-set>
```

I would like, in my AS3 code, to be able to select specific data from this xml file.

Example :

```
var currentDate=new Date();
var day=currentDate.getDate();

If the day == one of the day of the xml, display "haute" of the corresponding day.
```

Is it possible ? How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you are looking by filtering your xml data by attribute or element, for more details take a look [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e6b.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e60).

So for you example, you can do like this :

```
var xml:XML = 
    <data-set xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <record>
            <Date>1 July</Date>
            <Ville>New-York</Ville>
            <haute>6h50</haute>
            <basse>1h14</basse>
            <haute2>20h01</haute2>
            <basse2>13h16</basse2>
        </record>
        <record>
            <Date>2 July</Date>
            <Ville>New-York</Ville>
            <haute>7h36</haute>
            <basse>1h59</basse>
            <haute2>20h41</haute2>
            <basse2>13h56</basse2>
        </record>
        <record>
            <Date>3 July</Date>
            <Ville>Miami</Ville>
            <haute>8h21</haute>
            <basse>2h44</basse>
            <haute2>21h22</haute2>
            <basse2>14h37</basse2>
        </record>
    </data-set>
;

var search:XMLList = xml.record.(Date == '3 July');
if(search){
    trace(search.haute);    // gives : 8h21
}
```

And when loading data from an external file :

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(); 
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, on_xml_loaded);
    loader.load(new URLRequest('xml.xml'));

function on_xml_loaded(e:Event){
    var xml:XML = new XML(e.target.data);
    var search:XMLList = xml.record.(Date == '3 July');
    if(search){
        trace(search.haute);    // gives : 8h21
    }
}
```

Hope that can help.